# SPO: get a list Remote Event Receivers subscribed to some List

Tags: list, workflow, remote-event-receiver

I've searched a lot about it but didn't find anything about it.

Is there any way to get the list of Remote Event receivers subscribed to a List and its remote endpoint?

I'm currently managing an existing Site in SPO, I'll explain my case:

There are two lists, A and B.

When a record form A is updated, some values are copied to a corresponding record in B (Linked by "Title" value based on my observations).

There is no Flow or javascript configured on these lists.
I'm site collection administrator, so I expect to have enough permisions to see all existing flows on site. Actually there are some flows, but they work on other lists. But For lists A & B there are no flows attached.

I expect to be some add-In attached to it and some server-side code running anywhere (webapp in azure or something like that).

Thank you